# can't get movieClip from loaded swf

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

With following code  I import an external swf file. When I try to reach a movieClip that is named as temaResim in imported swf, Flash gives me error ,cant find the movieclip. I am pretty sure that I have temaResim in imported swf file, any help will be very useful.

Thanks guys.

```js
function temaYukle(temaNo)
  {
   var resim:URLRequest = new URLRequest(yolum+"videolar/bilisselbecerilermodulu/17/"+temaNo+".swf");
   var img:Loader = new Loader();
   img.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, imageLoaded);
   img.load(resim);
   function imageLoaded(e:Event):void
   {
    setRegPoint(img,img.width/2,img.height/2);

    if (temaNo==temam)
    {
     trace(e.target);
     tema = e.currentTarget.content as MovieClip;
     img.scaleX *=  0.85;
     img.scaleY *=  0.85;
     img.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
     img.y = stage.stageHeight / 2 - 20;
     addChildAt(img,0);
// here comes error         
trace(tema.temaResim);
     
     temaMaske();
    }
              }
          }
```

I worked on imported swf file When i import onther image to library of imported swf and set it's instance name  as temaResim it works but When I try the image that ı have to, it dosn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **Bracket syntax**:

```
function temaYukle(temaNo)
    {
        var resim:URLRequest = new URLRequest(yolum+"videolar/bilisselbecerilermodulu/17/"+temaNo+".swf");
        var img:Loader = new Loader();
        img.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, imageLoaded);
        img.load(resim);
        function imageLoaded(e:Event):void
        {
            setRegPoint(img,img.width/2,img.height/2);

            if (temaNo==temam)
            {
                trace(e.target);
                tema = e.currentTarget.content as MovieClip;
                img.scaleX *=  0.85;
                img.scaleY *=  0.85;
                img.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
                img.y = stage.stageHeight / 2 - 20;
                addChildAt(img,0);
// here comes error                     
trace(img.content["temaResim"]);

                temaMaske();
            }
          }
      }
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I tried trace(tema["resimTema"]); but still have no solution

Comment: try to use img.content["resimTema"] instead of tema["temaResim"]

Comment: ReferenceError: Error #1069: _2_fla.maintimeline__preloader__ temaResim feature not found and has no default value.

Comment: so your swf seems not to have this property. I tried it for my own and worked for me.do you want a proof?

Comment: I worked on imported swf file When i import onther image to library of imported swf and set it's instance name as temaResim it works but When I try the image that ı have to, it dosn't work.,The problem is not with code, it is with loaded swf file.

Answer (score 1):

İt is unbelievable but true, I have to change the ımage That has name temaResim, Now it works,

Answer (score 0):

Not the LoaderInfo holds the content ;-)

```
tema = e.currentTarget.loader.content as MovieClip;
```

Comment: thank you very much, I tried your code but I have the same error message

Comment: try `img.content  as MovieClip`. You dont need to referrer double. Further give us the output of `trace(img.content)` in your `if`-condition. AND the errormessage.

Comment: Ah, and be sure to add the content to stage, not the loader